# Show full post in category archive pages in twenty-nineteen theme

Tags: child-theme, archives

I am using twenty nineteen theme. It shows only the excerpt in the category archive page. I would like to show the full post.

I created a child theme and copied the file archive.php to the child folder.

It has the following instructions.

```
* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
* If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
* called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'excerpt' );
```

I am not sure what to do here.

I tried renaming this file to content-archive.php and replacing the line "get_template_part..." with "the_content();"

Nothing happens.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In archive.php, change this line (36) from

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'excerpt' );
```

to this

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'content' );
```